# Need a little help populating in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

So I've spent the past two days trying to learn enough VBA script to automatically populate a spreadsheet when a new one arrives from a supplier via a macro. Long story short, I haven't yet figured it out. I am now using this formula `=IF($A$1="", "", INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'[",$A$1,"]Tester'!A12")))` to update cells after copying the new sheet into my workbook and placing the name of the new sheet in row A then copy and pasting the new formula below the old entries. Unfortunately the "Tester'A12" part of my formula is not increasing with the cell number of my columns (i.e A12 does not turn into A13, A14, etc.) I was wondering if anyone knew a way I could fix this. I may be missing something super simple. Thank you for your time!

Comment: You have it in quotes...so it is a string, not a variable or a cell

Comment: =IF($A$1="", "", INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'[",$A$1,"]Tester'!"&A12)))

Comment: removing the quotes produces an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF($A$1="", "", INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'[",$A$1,"]Tester'!A" & ROW())))
```

If the formula is on row 1, it will get the tester A1. If you need, add or subtract from it like

```
=IF($A$1="", "", INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'[",$A$1,"]Tester'!A" & ROW()+3)))
```

or

```
=IF($A$1="", "", INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'[",$A$1,"]Tester'!A" & ROW()-5)))
```

Comment: this is now returning zero for every cell. The formula is going into row 500 something but pulling from row 12 down on Tester

Comment: `=IF($A$1="", "", INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'[",$A$1,"]Tester'!A" & ROW()-488)))` because 500-488 = 12, which is the starting value you want. Then the formula on the next row will be 501-488, which will return 13.